# PHP array to javascript loop vs json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, laravel

Hello guys i am a newbie laravel develop and in my blade i have a php var $x and this is an array!

My question what is the best method and when to apply each method?

My first metho is loop with foreach for exemple:

```
 <script>
  var javascript = [];
        @foreach($x as $value)
          javascript[$loop->index] = $value;
        @endforeach
  </script>
```

My second method is with @json or json_encode

```
<script>
  var javascript = @json($x);
</script>
```

What method is the best?? When to aply diferent methods?

Sorry for this newbie question!!
Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is a broad question, but the JSON is always going to be more robust. For example, there is a trivial string injection vulnerability in the first code sample, both for the key and the value.

Comment: WHy not do a `json_encode()` in the controller and pass the JSON to the blade already set

Comment: I think it would come down to preference, but it might be best to go with the json_encode method as it will give you valid/parseable javascript everytime.

Comment: Json encode will compose that array into json string, meanwhile array element initialization will create element value, so how to compare two different value type?

Comment: Thanks you all for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to just use JSON like you did with `@json`. This is very safe, because JSON syntax always makes for valid JavaScript expression.

It's even mentioned in the documentation, under [Displaying Data](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#displaying-data).

Your first example is unnecessarily complicated and meant only for numeric-indexed arrays, so PHP's associative arrays won't work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer